# How to solve this property of discrete Markov property?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> The Markov condition
>
> $P(X_n=s|X_0=x_0,...,X_{n-1}=x_{n-1})=(X_n=s|X_{n-1}=x_{n-1})$ for all $n\geq1$ and all $s,x_0,...,x_{n-1} \in S$
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> $P(X_{n+m}=s|X_0=x_0,...,X_{n}=x_{n})=(X_{n+m}=s|X_{n}=x_{n})$ for any $n,m \geq1$

Is easy show the $\leftarrow$ implication $(m=1)$.

But, i'm stuck in the other way. If i try to use the theorem of total probability i get $P(X_{n+m}=s|X_{n+m-1}=x_{n+m-1})$. Can you help me?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3177294/36150)